# How high can an unprotected second level be in a hamster cage?

Tags: safety, hamsters

I have read that hamsters must be protected from injury due to accidental falls.

I am starting to make DIY hamster toys out of cardboard, wood and Popsicle sticks.

I know that my hamster can comfortably climb onto his igloo (3 inches high) and can comfortably hop down.

- What is a safe height?
- How high can I make a second level?
- At what height do I need to make little walls around a second level platform, to prevent the hamster from falling off the precipice?

I've seen some DIY images that look terrifying, but maybe I'm interpreting the cautions too literally?  Here's an example:

[image: Scary looking hamster edifice]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the standard hamster cages out there I wouldn't worry too much about your little guy falling to his death, mainly since those cages aren't built very big and generally has a good amount of bedding at the bottom.

With your popsicle stick hamster fort I would not worry about it being too tall, assuming it is going in a regular hamster cage, my main concern would be the glue that holds it together if your hamster would ingest it - they love to chew, chew, chew! Try to search for a glue that is labeled pet safe.

If you are making a large enclosure for your hamster I would stay cautious and build no more than 1ft high and be sure to have a good amount of bedding. I would also incorporate a couple ramps and tubes to the structure to give him a selection of ways to get around safely.

Overall it depends on how they land from the fall, I have had hamsters fall from 3-4ft without a scratch and have seen some that died of internal bleeding or broke a leg.